# How to search the change log?

Tags: contacts, user

The docs on synchronizing users to contacts say:

> You can then search your contact records to view or edit the new
> contact records. Go to Advanced Search , >>Change Log section and
> enter dates that include the date when the synchronization was
> performed.

But on my Advanced Search page, there is no Change Log section. Has this changed? How do you search the change log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Display Preferences where it says "Contact Search". It has probably been unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just want to comment that this option seems oddly out of place in Display Preferences. Shouldn't Contact Search options be in Search Preferences?